# Best Practice for PhoneGap/Django login

Tags: jquery, django, cordova

I am looking for a best practice insight on how to handle logins with PhoneGap and Django.  Django has a protection token against a Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attack.  On a typical Django server with a typical page the token is rendered as part of the Form.  This is easy enough to handle for a website but brings up the issue of how to do it with a PhoneGap app.

I am trying to get insight as to what is a best practice strategy on how to do this.  Right now I've got working GET calls, but need to make the POST work for user & pwd.  Here are strategies that I am looking at:

1) Get the full form rendered from the client

2) Get the CSRF token from an AJAX call and add it as a hidden field to the form

3) Some other suggestion...  :)

I am also trying to get accurate info on how PhoneGap handles cookies so I can use a session key.  There seems to be conflicting information our there.

I'm using PG 2.7.0 with JQ 1.9.1 & JQM 1.3.1.

Any insight anyone has will be greatly welcome.

Comment: You can bypass csrf protection if you don't need it.

Comment: I thought of that but I'm looking for a good strategy with the CSRF token.  I've seen too many sites get compromised this way and would like to avoid the security hole.

Comment: It's not terribly difficult to pick up the CSRF token via JavaScript for Ajax posts: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax